# Inserting a Record with PHP5.4 and MSSQL causes duplicates

Tags: php, sql-server

I have an issue that I have not been able to solve with PHP v5.4.24 NTS, MS SQL 2008 R2 under IIS 7.

When I perform the following code:

```
$key1_wanted = '86586';

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( DATABASE_HOST, array( "UID"=>DB_USER, 
                        "PWD"=>DB_PWD, "Database"=>DATABASE_NAME));

$sql = "INSERT INTO Clients_Archives SELECT *,GETDATE() FROM clients 
        WHERE client_num=    $key1_wanted";
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
```

I get two records inserted.  I have tried with PDO_SQLSRV and SQLSRV v3 drivers with no luck and have switched PHP versions and driver versions.

Frank

Comment: how many results do you get for just running the select query inside SQL Server Management Studio? `SELECT *,GETDATE() FROM clients WHERE client_num='86586'`

Comment: Are you certain that the snippet of code above is executing only once? If it's in a loop or a function that's called multiple times, you'll get more than one insert.

Comment: Yup the code above is only executed a single time.

Comment: Also Watcher the code when issued from within SQL Studio only a single record is created.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after reseting my development VM I have found the issue.  It was Chrome v35.0.1916.114 m causing some issues.  Now to get back my lost 4 days of developmetn